# How do I solve this unicode error (SyntaxError) in Jupytor Notebook while loading the csv file onto the notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I am unable to get rid of this unicode error. I have tried all the other ways to represent the address, that is using '/', '//', '' and '\'. None of these work. Please help me out in solving this error.

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\windows\Desktop\USA_Housing.csv')
df.head()
```

[image]

If I use 'r' before the address, I am getting 10 more errors. They are as follows in the picture given below.

enter image description here

[image]

Comment: use `pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\windows\Desktop\USA_Housing.csv')`

Comment: @mozway I have tried that too. I get 10 more errors after doing that. UnicodeDecodeError

Comment: then provide the code and full traceback

Comment: @mozway Here are the images that  show all the errors after performing the above act.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GlhxKDxz0ePR86AXaT9gtpqDkrVS8bTj?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, you should provide all info directly in the question, and as nicely formatted **text**.

Comment: @mozway Okay, done. I have edited the question properly. Now please do try to resolve my issue. Thank you.